# looping over folders

Tags: r

I posted this question earlier but I like to repeat it again.

I have 50 folders. Each folder consists of 40 rasters. Each raster has a value that I need to extract. These rasters share the same x&y. Finally, I need to put them all in one data frame. To do so, I tried to run a loop to read all rasters from all folders and combine them by row. For example, I have 50 Rain rasters, so these will fall under the same column and so on. Is there any way to do that?

Here are the codes:

```
Reading <- function(raster) {
  df <- stack(raster)
}

All_raster <- dir("E:/50_folders/", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern=".tif$")# This is to read rasters from 50 folders
All_tif <- sapply(All_raster, Reading)
ALl_tif <- as.data.frame(All_tif , xy =TRUE)
```

And this is the error I get
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")’ to a data.frame

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If an earlier question does not get an answer then please edit that earlier question to improve it.

Comment: It seems like you made this as a [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324443/converting-list-of-raster-to-a-data-frame-using-r#comment528575_324446) so it is probably not a duplicate after all, but it is a coding question.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.