# Get values from raster file in R

Tags: raster, r, data

I have never used satellite data and I'm using NASA's information of PM2.5 "Global Annual PM2.5 Grids from MODIS, MISR and SeaWiFS Aerosol Optical Depth (AOD), 1998-2019, V4.GL.03", I got it from [here](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules?p=C2208962437-SEDAC&pg%5B0%5D%5Bv%5D=f&pg%5B0%5D%5Bgsk%5D=-start_date&q=MAIAC&fi=MODIS&tl=1693764483.504!3!!&fst0=Atmosphere). It is a 1 km resolution of PM2.5.

I want to get information of PM2.5 only for a certain area: xlim = c(-115.21,-115.763246), ylim = c(32.38, 32.702345) and for xlim = c(-116.903885, -117.142257),ylim = c(32.35, 32.591890).

When I download the data I get a folder with 6 files. I'm trying to work with the .tif.ovr file.

I understand that I need to read the raster

```
n14 <- "~/nasa2014.tif.ovr"
r <- raster(n14)
```

but I don't understand how to access the data. I saw this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324443/converting-list-of-raster-to-a-data-frame-using-r) but it didn't work.

My file looks like this:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 6250, 18000, 112500000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 18000, 0, 6250  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : nasa2014.tif.ovr 
names      : nasa2014.tif
```

Comment: is there a _nasa2014.tif_ file among your files? If so, try to import that file instead of the _nasa2014.tif.ovr_. Also, it's better to use the `terra` package instead of the `raster`, like so: `r <- rast(nasa2014.tif)`.

Comment: yes, you were right, I have a .tif that when I read it with `terra ` I get
`.class : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 12500, 36000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -55, 70  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : sdei-global-annual-gwr-pm2-5-modis-misr-seawifs-aod-v4-gl-03-2014.tif 
name        : sdei-global-annual-gwr-pm2-5-m~misr-seawifs-aod-v4-gl-03-2014 
min value   :0.6 
max value   : 189.1 `

Answer (score 0):

The `.ovr` file contains "overview" images - lower-resolution versions of the main data file to make mapping at low resolutions quicker, for software that understands it.

If you try creating a `terra` raster from the overviews file, it will tell you it doesn't have a known extent, and map it to coordinates 1:n, 1:m.

```
> ovr = rast("./popdens.tif.ovr")
Warning message:
[rast] unknown extent 
> ext(ovr)
SpatExtent : 0, 268, 0, 217 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Compare with reading the `tif` file itself:

```
> tif = rast("./popdens.tif")
> ext(tif)
SpatExtent : 152881.239999998, 166256.239999998, 378970.300700001, 389795.300700001 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```